# Bounty notification doesn’t show title

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, email

I don’t recall putting a bounty on … \… and what about it, anyways? That’s a fragment. We should consider revising it.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well, with all of the bounties that you have out would you even remember if you did have a bounty on ... \

Comment: Hey... I asked `... \ ` months ago, and you told me you liked the question so much you were gonna put a bounty on it, especially once @Servy answered it with `/ ...` C'mon!

Comment: Oh sure @AndrewBarber, but as soon as I answer it with the entirely reasonable `-...` you abuse your moderator privileges once again and delete the answer.

Comment: looking, fixing ....

Comment: @m0sa any updates? Just got such an email.

Comment: it happens only on meta.stackoverflow.com, and we haven't had any luck reproducing it on our dev machines.. we're still tracking it down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out meta SO is the only page that uses strings from our [automatically extracted](http://mattjibson.com/blog/2013/03/01/careers-localization-part-3-extraction/) database for the english -> english "localization" case.

So the cause for this bug was (of course) (again) localization.

The formatting on this particular email is fine again (kudos to @KevinMontrose):

[image]

Comment: +1... though I should get such email within few days so only then will know for sure. :)